# Comparing Individual Fields to Field Average (SQL)

Tags: sql, subquery

Here I am trying to compare the amounts to the average amount that people owe and display their names. I suspect a subselect would work but Im not sure how to make it work.

"name" is a field of players and "amount" is a field of penalties, and they have a common field of "playerno".

```
select name
from players, penalties
where amount > avg(amount);
```

Comment: what is the relation ship between players and penalties

Comment: Can you post your table structure? Thanks.

Comment: You probably didn't mean to implicitly cross-join `players` and `penalties`. Can you share the tables' structures, some sample data, and the result you're trying to get?

Comment: @AjanBalakumaran playerno

Comment: @oneshotone share sample data and expected result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below

```
select name
from players a inner join penalties b on a.playerno=b.playerno
where amount > 
(select avg(amount) from penalties );
```

Comment: Hahahaha I was late to find out that question owner has put a relationship.

Comment: @AjanBalakumaran, it's better to use explicit join instead comma separated join

Comment: Yes thats why I asked for a relationship in question comments that code part was taken from the question, I also don’t recommend explicit join

Answer (score 0):

Since average is an aggregation function you can do similar to below in SQL Server,

```
select name
from players, penalties
where amount > 
(select avg(amount) from players, penalties);
```